# C# out-parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, heap-memory, out

What is the difference between the following two code snippets?

```
public void foo(out classA x)
{
    y = new classA();
    x = y;
}
```

and the second:

```
public void foo(out classA x)
{
    classA y;
    x = y;
}
```

Is it true that the second snippet is dangerous, because `x` has now a reference to this local `y`, which might be already dead after exiting `foo`?

Why do we have to use "new" in general?

I'm a bit confused, because in C++, if `x` in the second snippet would be a pointer, the statement `x = y` would not even compile since `y` is not a pointer.

Comment: Neither of them compile.

Comment: The second one isn't dangerous. It's useless since you never assign a value to y.

Comment: In C#, classes are always allocated on the heap, so you would not have to worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion, I think, is that in C++ the second example would return a reference to a stack-allocated object. That doesn't happen in C#.

Given your second example in C#:

```
public void foo(out classA x)
{
  classA y;  // Doesn't allocate an object
  x = y;
}
```

This probably won't compile, anyway, because `y` is never assigned a value.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume for a moment that the second snippet is

```
public void foo(out classA x)
{
  classA y = new classA();
  x = y;
}
```

The snippet as you wrote it does not compile in C# at all. `y` has to be assigned first. The line `classA y;` does not create an instance of `classA` on the stack as it would in C++. It simply declares a variable `y` of type `classA`.

With the compiling snippet in mind, assigning an `out` variable to a locally declared and initialized object is not dangerous in any way. The `classA` object that `y` points to and that is assigned to `x` will remain alive and well until `x` goes out of scope wherever it's declared/used.

Comment: I'd like to add that .net uses reference counting to track the instances that are created, so unlike C++ where the instance you created locally would be de-allocated when it goes out of scope, the instance of `y` above does not go out of scope, rather one reference is added to it's "in use" count (x) and then one is subtracted (y) when the function exits.  When its "in use" count drops to 0, then the garbage collector can come along and actually remove it from memory.  At which point it is _really_ gone.

Comment: @CodingGorilla The .NET CLR doesn't use reference counting. The garbage collector walks the object tree and traces references that are no longer accessible by the running code.

Comment: You are correct, I was trying to explain the idea that the instance remains in memory as long as it's "in use", and that was a poor way to explain it (especially since reference counting is a completely different technique), but hopefully between the two of us he gets the idea.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that ClassA y does NOT create an object on the stack. In my actual problem I have a struct and with this both versions compile. I guess this is because structs are a value-type?!

Comment: @Juergen Yes, that's correct. Structs are a value type and behave a bit differently from classes. Still, far as your problem is concerned, the answer is the same: the second snippet is safe to use.

Comment: @Juergen: Correct, structs work differently from classes.  If it is a struct, declaring the local does in fact allocate the struct on the stack, and the two code snippets you provide are, I believe, identical in function.  The assignment statement copies the bits of y to the storage location of x.  It's just really confusing to have a struct named "classA"!  In general, it's not fruitful to worry about whether your .NET code is operating on the stack or the heap.  It's much more important to worry about reference-type vs. value-type semantics.

Comment: So, reference types have to be always instantiated with new? Thank you guys for the answers, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that the second snippet is dangerous [...]

Not in C#; you're thinking of native languages like C or C++ that allow one to take a pointer to a local variable. In C#, everything (within reason) is a reference to a managed object. Everything is essentially on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

It is not dangerous because the code will NOT be able to be compiled unless all "out" parameters are given a definition before the method returns or exits.